# Box2d Detect when a body is fully inside another body and which side it came in from

Tags: c++, box2d

I need to detect when a body is **fully inside** another body and **which side it came in from**.

I have balls that bounce around the screen, and can enter the space of other square bodies. I need to know when the ball is fully inside the box, and from which side it came in on. This is **NOT** just collision detection on a side of the box, as the ball needs to be fully inside the box before anything triggers. I'm using b2FixtureDef::filter::maskBits and b2FixtureDef::filter::categoryBits to allow balls and boxes to not collide with each other.

I'm new to box2d, but not to C++, so I may be missing some functions that could make this easier for me. I started writing the following code, which works when a ball passes the correct edge, but also when it passes other edges.

Is there a way to do this without copying the ball into another data structure that keeps track of where it first contacts the box?

NOTE: This code is an example. It may not actually compile or do exactly what I say it does.

```
void CBox::captureBalls(std::list<CBall> &balls)
{
    std::list<CBall> capturedBalls;

    std::list<CBall>::iterator ball = balls.begin();
    while (ball != balls.end()) {
        bool capture = false;
        int ballMinX = ball->getX() - ball->getRadius();
        int ballMaxX = ball->getX() + ball->getRadius();
        int ballMinY = ball->getY() - ball->getRadius();
        int ballMaxY = ball->getY() + ball->getRadius();

        switch (this->captureSide) {
            case Top:
                if ((ballMinX >= this->x) &&
                    (ballMaxX < (this->x + this->width)) &&
                    //(ballMinY >= this->y) &&
                    (ballMaxY < (this->y + this->height)))
                        capture = true;
                break;
            case Right:
                if (//(ballMinX >= this->x) &&
                    (ballMaxX < (this->x + this->width)) &&
                    (ballMinY >= this->y) &&
                    (ballMaxY < (this->y + this->height)))
                        capture = true;
                break;
            case Bottom:
                if ((ballMinX >= this->x) &&
                    (ballMaxX < (this->x + this->width)) &&
                    (ballMinY >= this->y) /*&&
                    (ballMaxY < (this->y + this->height))*/)
                        capture = true;
                break;
            case Left:
                if ((ballMinX >= this->x) &&
                    //(ballMaxX < (this->x + this->width)) &&
                    (ballMinY >= this->y) &&
                    (ballMaxY < (this->y + this->height)))
                        capture = true;
                break;
        }

        if (capture) {
            capturedBalls.push_back(ball);
            balls.erase(ball++);
        }
        else {
            ++ball;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to detect which side it came from, check dx, and dy of the ball once its inside, to see which direction its going

Comment: @sp2danny Since dx and dy are not actual members of the body class, I assume you are just giving general advice(I know what you mean by saying dx and dy). I am looking for how to specifically do this with box2d.

Comment: related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27320/in-box2d-how-can-i-check-for-bodies-within-a-circle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect when a ball is fully inside the box, you could use a sensor fixture inside the box, that is smaller than the box by the diameter of the ball. In the diagram below the black rectangle is the box and the red dashed rectangle is the sensor. (If the balls all have different diameters this would not work.)

As to "which side it came in", I think you need to define what you mean by that, before anyone could help. I mean, look at the possible cases you are dealing with. The blue ball is the most straight-forward in that it approaches on one side in a constant direction. When you detect that it touches the sensor, you could use the direction of travel as suggested by sp2danny, to do a raycast from outside the box to the current position of the ball, and the side it entered is pretty obvious. But this would not work for the green or pink balls. For the pink ball in particular, what side would you consider it entered from?[image]

Now I am assuming that the balls are free to enter the boxes from any angle. But if they had a solid obstruction at their corners, it might be clearer to define which side they came in. You could use four sensors around the exterior, and detect when a ball *finishes* touching these.[image]

However, it would not be bullet-proof because in rare cases a ball could go from touching one side sensor to another in one time step, without touching nothing in between (green ball). For really fast balls, they could also potentially go from touching one side sensor, to completely inside without ever touching the sensor for the side they "came in" (pink ball). On the plus side though, this would handle the case when you have many different sizes of ball.

Ok... now that I've written up a whole post saying how it can't be done easily, I had a good idea, although it would only work when all balls are the same size. You could use two sensors inside the box, one inset by the radius of the balls, and one inset by the diameter of the balls. When the ball first touches the outer of these sensors, it means the center of the ball has crossed from being outside, to inside the box (but the ball as a whole may not be fully inside). At this point, take a raycast between the previous and current positions, and note which side it intersected. Continue on until the ball also touches the inner sensor, then you know it is fully inside, and you have already noted which side it originally came in from. If the ball stops touching the outer sensor at any point, reset to the starting state.[image]

Note that it is still possible for a ball to first touch the box from one side, then move so that the first time its center is inside the box is from a different side (orange ball). But I am assuming you would not count a mere touch as "came in".

Comment: Awesome answer. The images really help explain it. Like I said, I'm new to box2d, so it looks like I have some reading to do and I might have to rethink how I'm doing things. I would upvote the answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.